# Do I need to specify 'drop(item)' if i write a custom drop implementation for a struct? Rust

Tags: rust

I'm working with OpenGL in rust currently.

and i want to create objects like VAOs and Textures into structs

now, i wrote a custom drop implementation that calls something like `glDeleteTexture` when the objects lifetime is finished so that it clears up the memory in VRAM.

Will the actual data of the object still remain in the RAM if i dont specifically call `drop(struct_attribute)` for all the attributes

I'm expecting for rust to automatically call drop on every attribute but i just wanna make sure so that i dont waste my time or memory if im wrong.

Comment: No. There's an implicit `drop` for every variable at the end of the scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to manually drop other members when you implement drop, nor would you be able to.

Take for example:

```rust
struct A {
    handle: i32,
    a: String,
    // ...
}

impl Drop for A {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        // Do something with `handle`
        // ...

        // `a` will be dropped *after* this function returns automatically
    }
}
```

`Drop::drop` receives a `&mut self`, which makes it so you cannot (without unsafe or replacing the original value) drop `self.a`. If you did somehow drop it, rust would then proceed to drop it again after `drop` returns, causing a double free.

`Drop` doesn't serve for dropping a type, despite it's name. It's more akin to a finalizer that runs code *right before* the type is dropped.

Comment: It's called drop because you are supposed to drop the resources you own that are not directly a part of the type, e.g. stuff stored via pointers or over FFI boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

`drop` is simply defined as `fn drop<T>(_: T) {}`, it does *absolutely* nothing special. Rust automatically picks up everything for you: *almost* every value is dropped by Rust (some exceptions include when the program diverges, but don't worry about it).